D3 support for network graph with area drawing
I want to create this using d3.js but I haven't found any samples or reference like it. I already tried it with d3-force and Voronoi diagrams. But it was not successful, has anyone done this before in a different way?
I want to create network graph with nodes and those node must group as different layers

